# Haskell | Struggling to understand type declaration and abbreviations

Tags: haskell, types

In a course I am following about Haskell, I am learning about type declaration. Currently, it is discussing abbreviations, something I am confused about, and that I cannot find the information I am looking for online.

It gives the following example:

```
type Pair a = (a, a)
```

along with a snippet of text: `Abbreviations - new name for existing types`

I have seen an example on the documentation that closely resembles the code above:

```
type Name = String
```

but from that I still cannot make sense of the above example.

I am struggling to understand what it is trying to explain, so can someone else make sense of it for me and give simple example of its usage in a program?

Comment: This is a type alias. It means that if you write in a signature for example `Pair Int`, then behind the curtains it resolves to `(Int, Int)`, the same with `Name` that will be replaced with `String`.

Comment: See https://wiki.haskell.org/Type_synonym

Comment: Would you be able to provide a real-world example of using it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [*type alias* [Haskell wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type_synonym). It is used to often give a name to more complicated types.

For example if you define a function:

```
sum2 :: Pair Int -> Int
sum2 (x, y) = x + y
```

then behind the curtains, this is thus resolved to:

```
sum2 :: (Int, Int) -> Int
sum2 (x, y) = x + y
```

Type aliases are often used to

1. to give a special structure a more convenient name;
2. to shorten complicated types; and
3. to make it easy to switch from type.

For example a `String` is defined as:

```
type String = [Char]
```

A `String` is thus simply a list of `Char`acters. But a signature with `String` focuses on the fact that it works with textual data.

Type aliases are often used to abstract away complexity of a type. For example we can define a type `Operator`:

```
type Operator a = a -> a -> a
```

This is thus an alias for a function that maps two parameters of type `a` to a value of type `a`. This is interesting if we later want to create functions that work with this operator. For example:

```
maxOperator :: Ord a => Operator a -> Operator a -> Operator a
maxOperator f g x y = max (f x y) (g x y)
```

This is more likely more readable than:

```
maxOperator :: Ord a => (a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a)
maxOperator f g x y = max (f x y) (g x y)
```

and it definitely is more readable if we would later use `Operator (Operator a)`, which thus resolves to `(a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> a -> a -> a`.

Finally types are sometimes used if it is not yet completely clear what type you will use. If you are for example implementing a package and you have not yet decided to work with `Float`s or `Double`s, you can define a type alias:

```
type Scalar = Float
```

If you then later change your mind, you can rewrite it to `type Scalar = Double`, and all places where you used `Scalar` will now resolve to `Double`.

Comment: Fantastic. I see now, it is *essentially* to make everything more readable, understandable, and all things related. It, of course, adds functionality with your last example, but it's purpose is to abstract away from the unnecessary *behind-the-scenes* stuff. Thanks, Willem, it totally makes sense now :)

Answer (score 4):

When you write a statement with the `type` keyword, you are defining a type *synonym*. Thus in the following example, the type `Pair Int` and the type `(Int, Int)` are *exactly the same type* and can be used interchangeably:

```
type Pair a = (a, a)

myPair :: Pair Int
myPair = (1, 2)

sumPair :: Num a => Pair a -> a
sumPair = uncurry (+)
```

This example works even though the type of `uncurry` specifies a two-tuple instead of a `Pair` because a `Pair` *is* a two-tuple.

This contrasts with the similar declaration `newtype`, which defines a wrapper around another type. In the following example, the types `Pair Int` and `(Int, Int)` are distinct at compile-time and cannot be used interchangeably:

```
newtype Pair a = Pair { unpair :: (a, a) }

myPair :: Pair Int
myPair = Pair (1, 2)

sumPair :: Num a => Pair a -> a
sumPair = uncurry (+) . unpair
```

It is necessary in the second example to call `Pair` to wrap the two-tuple into a pair before assigning it to `myPair` and `unpair` to unwrap the pair into a standard two-tuple before we can use `uncurry` because `Pair Int` and `(Int, Int)` are treated as distinct types.